# Can't connect to MySQL 5.0 with ColdFusion 6.1 + JRun

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, jrun

Obviously, this is not a desirable platform in 2011.  :-)  HOWEVER. . . .

I was using ColdFusion 6.1 and JRun to connect to MySQL on another host.  It seemed like it connected okay, but I kept getting:

```
[]java.sql.SQLException: Invalid authorization specification: Access denied for user 'user'@'hostname' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that connecting with a user having no password worked.  After looking at [MySQL documentation](http://diigo.com/0fzjp) and trying out a few things, I still couldn't get passwords to work, even using "OLD_PASSWORD()".  Guess I'm stuck with a password-less login for now.

Comment: Make sure you're not using a password over 15 characters, that would break it. (don't you love old platforms?)